# Did Harry originally intend for Veronica to sell his criminal notebook and come to no further harm?

Tags: plot-explanation, widows

In Steve McQueen's twisty cerebral heist movie, [Widows](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4218572/?ref_=nv_sr_1), a group of criminal's widows enact Harry Rawling's next criminal plan.

He leaves clues so that his wife, Veronica, can find the notebook containing the plan. Presumably so she could benefit from the money raised without taking any risk.

> It later also transpires that he didn't die but planned for the next heist to happen and to heist the heist leaving others to take the blame (given he was supposed to be dead and couldn't be blamed).

Was this his intended plan?

Comment: This part was so confusing. Wish someone had answered you.

Answer (score 1):

If you remember, Bobby Welsh (the guy in the wheelchair) told Veronica to just give the book to Jamal and forget about it.  While not *explicitly* clear, it's *implicit* that Veronica was to give Jamal the book to erase Harry's debt, and then have Jamal steal the money from Mulligan.  Whether Welch knew Harry was alive or not is never known, but presumably before they robbed Jamal, Harry had likely told Welch to guide his wife towards giving the book to Jamal in the event of his death.

Answer (score 0):

> Did Harry originally intend for Veronica to sell his criminal notebook
> ?

Maybe yes maybe no.
At the end of the movie, Harry say to Veronica :
*It's meant to be simple. Why couldn't you just sell the book to Jamal*

> and come to no further harm?

I'm not sure about this.

Anyway I think Harry will further harm her in such condition:
Harry rob Jamal 2 Million USD
It seems the deal with Mulligan after Harry rob Jamal 2 Million, 
Harry will give Mulligan 1 Million, as in the boat Mulligan say to Harry : 
*I want the full amount, Harry. One Million, like we agreed. 

I want that money. If not, you're gonna be alive again*

So that means, Harry has not give full 1 Million to Mulligan.

Then Harry say to Mulligan: 
*I can get your money, but I need time.*

This part is quite confusing to me, because it raise a question :
*Why Harry need time ? Why didn't Harry just give the 1 million full to Mulligan while Harry has the other 1 million for himself alone?*

So I think at this point, Harry didn't care at all of Veronica that she rob the 5 million from Mulligan.
Harry deliberately use Veronica to do the robbery, hoping his wife will succeed, then he plan to rob his wife (kill his wife if necessary) the 5 million and pay Mulligan full one million.

So, back to your first question...
What he said to Veronica maybe it's just a lip-service to her, because even if Veronica sell the book to Jamal, say for 1 million (because Jamal will get 5 million if he succeed the robbery on Mulligan's money) - Harry will rob that 1 million from Veronica to pay Mulligan.